# Being ddos-ed or my VPS has been compromised?

Tags: linux, security, bandwidth, vps, denial-of-service

- VPS bandwidth was suspended due to over usage.
- Didn't really promote my website at all cus it is still under development.
- Installed IFTOP and below is what I have captured.

  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcetw.png]

Any advice is greatly appreciated cus I am at a lost now.

Comment: You have high TX, if you were being attacked, your statistics would be flipped and RX would be high.  Another possibility is you miscalculated how much you have transferred from the server

Answer (score 2):

While you can't gain a lot of information from the output of iftop, that server is connecting to a number of mail servers.

If you're not expecting to be sending emails, then the server is compromised and should be shut down.